# Android bitmap compression and SQLite lock

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to make an app where I can import a picture, add some details and then save this information to an SQLite database on the device. Before adding the details to the database I compress and save the image to the device. I am getting a problem when I select a large image i.e. one from the camera and it causes a database lock? yet when save the details without the image it succeeds. please see my below code and errors:

Database:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "showcaseManager";

// Showcase table name
private static final String TABLE_SHOWCASE = "showcase";

// Showcase Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";

private static DatabaseHandler mInstance = null;

public static String Lock = "dblock";

public static DatabaseHandler getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHandler();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private DatabaseHandler() {
    super(MainActivity.getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SHOWCASE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOWCASE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT," + KEY_RATING + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SHOWCASE_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHOWCASE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new item. ##Correct##
public void addItem(ShowcaseItemLite item) {
    Log.v("Database", "Adding Item 1/2: " + item.getName());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getName()); // Item Name
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, item.getDescription()); // Item Description
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, item.getCompressedImagePath()); // Item Image Path
    values.put(KEY_RATING, item.getRating()); // Item Rating

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_SHOWCASE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    Log.v("Database", "Item added 2/2.");
}

// Getting single item. ##Correct##
public ShowcaseItemLite getItem(int id) {
    Log.v("Database", "Getting item 1/2: " + id);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SHOWCASE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_RATING }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ShowcaseItemLite item = new ShowcaseItemLite(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    item.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
    item.setImagePath(cursor.getString(3));
    item.setRating(Float.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)));

    Log.v("Database", "Item Got 2/2: " + cursor.getString(1));

    // return item
    return item;
}

// Getting All Items. ##Correct##
public List<ShowcaseItemLite> getAllItems() {
    Log.v("Database", "Getting all items 1/2.");
    List<ShowcaseItemLite> itemList = new ArrayList<ShowcaseItemLite>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SHOWCASE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ShowcaseItemLite item = new ShowcaseItemLite(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            item.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            item.setCompressedImagePath(cursor.getString(3));
            item.setRating(Float.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)));

            // Adding Item to list
            itemList.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.v("Database", "Received all items 2/2. Amount: " + itemList.size());
    // return item list
    return itemList;
}

// Updating single item. ##Correct##
public int updateItem(ShowcaseItemLite item) {
    Log.v("Database", "Updating Item 1/2: " + item.getName());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getName());
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, item.getDescription());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, item.getImagePath());

    // updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_SHOWCASE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getDatabaseID()) });

    db.close();

    Log.v("Database", "Item Updated 2/2");

    return i;
}

// Deleting single item
public void deleteItem(ShowcaseItemLite item) {
    synchronized(Lock) {
        Log.v("Database", "Deleting Item 1/2: " + item.getName());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_SHOWCASE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getDatabaseID()) });
        db.close();
        Log.v("Database", "Item deleted 2/2: ");
    }
}


// Getting items Count
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v("Database", "Preparing to get Item Count 1/2. ");
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SHOWCASE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    Log.v("Database", "Received item count 2/2: " + count);

    // return count
    return count;
}
}
```

Item class:

```
public class ShowcaseItemLite {

private String name;
private String description;
private String imagePath;
private float rating;
private String file_path = MainActivity.getStorageFilePath();
private int databaseID = 0;
private String thumbnailStoredLoc;
private String compressedImageStoredLoc;

public ShowcaseItemLite(int databaseID){
    this.setDatabaseID(databaseID);
}

public ShowcaseItemLite(String name, String description, String imagePath, float rating){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.rating = rating;

}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public String getImagePath(){
    return imagePath;
}

public float getRating(){
    return rating;
}

public int getDatabaseID() {
    return databaseID;
}

public void setDatabaseID(int databaseID) {
    this.databaseID = databaseID;
}

public String getFile_path() {
    return file_path;
}

public void setFile_path(String file_path) {
    this.file_path = file_path;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public void setRating(float rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}


public void saveImageAndThumb(int imageID){
    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Preparing to store images.");
    if(imagePath != null && !imagePath.equals("")){
        try{
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(dir, "I"+imageID+".bmp");
            if(!file.exists()){

                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                Bitmap bitmap = shrinkBitmap(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                //bitmap.recycle();

                this.compressedImageStoredLoc = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
                Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Saved image path: " + compressedImageStoredLoc);
            }else{
                Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Image exists. Skipping creation: " + file.toString());
                this.compressedImageStoredLoc = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(dir, "T"+imageID+".bmp");
            if(!file.exists()){
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                Bitmap bitmap = shrinkBitmapToThumb(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                this.thumbnailStoredLoc = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            }else{
                Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Thumbnail exists. Skipping creation: " + file.toString());
                this.thumbnailStoredLoc = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}

private Bitmap shrinkBitmap(String file){
    int height = 200;
    int width = 200;

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
    {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
        {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
        }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap shrinkBitmapToThumb(String file){
    int height = 100;
    int width = 100;

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
    {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
        {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
        }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
}

public String getImageThumbnailPath() {
    if(thumbnailStoredLoc == null){
        if(compressedImageStoredLoc != null){
            return getCompressedImagePath().replace("I", "T");
        }else{
            return null;
        }   
    }else{
        return thumbnailStoredLoc;
    }
}

public String setImageThumbnailPath() {
    return thumbnailStoredLoc;
}

public String getCompressedImagePath() {
    return compressedImageStoredLoc;
}

public void setCompressedImagePath(String image) {
    this.compressedImageStoredLoc = image;
}
}
```

New item class:

```
public class NewItemActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 0;
public static int TAKE_IMAGE = 111;
private String selectedImagePath = null;
private ImageView imageView;
private String selectedCameraPath;
private int itemID;

public NewItemActivity() {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_item);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newItemImageView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    itemID = extras.getInt("newID");
    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "New ImageID: " + itemID);

    Button galleryButton =((Button) findViewById(R.id.galleryButton));

    galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    Button cameraButton =((Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton));

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewItemActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            NewItemActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }        
    });

    Button saveButton =((Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton));

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText nameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTextField);
            String nameTextFieldString = nameTextField.getText().toString();
            EditText descriptionTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextField);
            String descriptionTextFieldString = descriptionTextField.getText().toString();
            RatingBar rating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.newRatingbar);

            Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "SelectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);

            if(!nameTextFieldString.equals("")){
                if(descriptionTextFieldString.equals("")){
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Creating Item 1/3." + "ItemID: " + itemID);
                    ShowcaseItemLite item = new ShowcaseItemLite(nameTextFieldString,"No Description.",selectedImagePath,rating.getRating());
                    item.saveImageAndThumb(itemID);
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Item created 2/3.");
                    DatabaseHandler.getInstance().addItem(item);
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Item added 3/3.");
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Creating Item 1/3.");
                    ShowcaseItemLite item = new ShowcaseItemLite(nameTextFieldString, descriptionTextFieldString, selectedImagePath, rating.getRating());
                    item.saveImageAndThumb(itemID);
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Item created 2/3.");
                    DatabaseHandler.getInstance().addItem(item);
                    Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Item added 3/3.");
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_item, menu);
    return true;
}

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath  = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE){
            String cameraPath = data.getStringExtra("location");
            Log.v("IMAGE_SAVE_LOG", "Camera image location: " + cameraPath);
            selectedCameraPath = cameraPath;
            //imageView.setImageURI(cameraPath);
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     database.DatabaseHandler.addItem(DatabaseHandler.java:77)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     showcasen.NewItemActivity$3.onClick(NewItemActivity.java:84)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-09 20:34:42.610: E/AndroidRuntime(8970):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

In several methods (`getItem`, `getAllItems`, etc.) you are opening a database connection and then not closing it. Make sure you always close it after opening it.

Even better, open it just once on startup, and reuse the same connection throughout your app's lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It has become more reactive now but I still get this error :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure the your image you are inserting isn't large. I found that my image were around 6MB !! and the db did not like this. 
You want to try and get the image to around 0.3 MB (300 KB).

You can find this out by calling this code on the image bytes

```
someImageBytes.length
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says the context passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` was null.

You seem to be passing `MainActivity.getContext()` there. That's not right. Pass in a context that is valid where you need the database. For example, in `NewItemActivity` is could be `NewItemActivity.this` or even `getApplicationContext()`.

Also note that you can use an activity, service or an application as a context only at `onCreate()`, not earlier.

Why it occurs with large images is because apps and activities are killed on low memory situations and when `NewItemActivity` is recreated, it doesn't recrete `MainActivity`.